# Checkbox that will search DB for boolean - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-view-controller

I have a search form and I need a checkbox that will select and then return whether a particular listing allows pets. I have created a custom route, controller method, and erb in the view. However, I am not accomplishing what I set out to do.

When a user clicks the `Pets Allowed` checkbox and then clicks search, the listings where pets allowed == true should be returned. I am not sure how to go about that.

This is the current code, but does not accomplish what I am after. This will redirect to /pets_allowed but that isn't a real thing.

listings_controller:

```
def pets_allowed
  @listings = Listing.where(pets: true)
end
```

routes.rb:

```
get "pets_allowed" => "listings#pets_allowed"
```

html.erb:

```
<div>
  <%= link_to 'Pets Allowed', pets_allowed_path, :class => 'button btn-transparent' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the search form code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `form_for` instead of `link_to`.

```
<%= form_for :search_pets, url: pets_allowed_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :has_pets %>
<% end %>
```

Now in action,

```
def pets_allowed
  @listings = Listing.where(pets: params[:search_pets][:has_pets])
end
```

When the checkbox is unchecked, it will return all the listings with no pets and when its checked it will return all the listings that have pets.

Hope that helps!